# Can get data in json in Python

Tags: python, json

I try to have the stock and some data of this URL:
[https://api.nvidia.partners/edge/product/search?page=1&limit=9&locale=fr-fr&category=GPU&gpu=RTX%203090,RTX%203080%20Ti,RTX%203080,RTX%203070%20Ti,RTX%203070,RTX%203060%20Ti,RTX%203060,RTX%203050%20Ti&manufacturer=NVIDIA&gpu_filter=RTX%203090~1,RTX%203080%20Ti~1,RTX%203080~1,RTX%203070%20Ti~1,RTX%203070~1,RTX%203060%20Ti~1,RTX%203060~0,RTX%203050%20Ti~0,RTX%203050~0,RTX%202080%20SUPER~0,RTX%202080~0,RTX%202070%20SUPER~0,RTX%202070~0,RTX%202060%20SUPER~0,RTX%202060~0,GTX%201660%20Ti~0,GTX%201660%20SUPER~0,GTX%201660~0,GTX%201650%20Ti~0,GTX%201650%20SUPER~0,GTX%201650~0](https://api.nvidia.partners/edge/product/search?page=1&limit=9&locale=fr-fr&category=GPU&gpu=RTX%203090,RTX%203080%20Ti,RTX%203080,RTX%203070%20Ti,RTX%203070,RTX%203060%20Ti,RTX%203060,RTX%203050%20Ti&manufacturer=NVIDIA&gpu_filter=RTX%203090%7E1,RTX%203080%20Ti%7E1,RTX%203080%7E1,RTX%203070%20Ti%7E1,RTX%203070%7E1,RTX%203060%20Ti%7E1,RTX%203060%7E0,RTX%203050%20Ti%7E0,RTX%203050%7E0,RTX%202080%20SUPER%7E0,RTX%202080%7E0,RTX%202070%20SUPER%7E0,RTX%202070%7E0,RTX%202060%20SUPER%7E0,RTX%202060%7E0,GTX%201660%20Ti%7E0,GTX%201660%20SUPER%7E0,GTX%201660%7E0,GTX%201650%20Ti%7E0,GTX%201650%20SUPER%7E0,GTX%201650%7E0)

And my script is:

```py
import json
import requests
import webbrowser


url = "https://api.nvidia.partners/edge/product/search?page=1&limit=9&locale=fr-fr&category=GPU&gpu=RTX%203090,RTX%203080%20Ti,RTX%203080,RTX%203070%20Ti,RTX%203070,RTX%203060%20Ti,RTX%203060,RTX%203050%20Ti&manufacturer=NVIDIA&gpu_filter=RTX%203090~1,RTX%203080%20Ti~1,RTX%203080~1,RTX%203070%20Ti~1,RTX%203070~1,RTX%203060%20Ti~1,RTX%203060~0,RTX%203050%20Ti~0,RTX%203050~0,RTX%202080%20SUPER~0,RTX%202080~0,RTX%202070%20SUPER~0,RTX%202070~0,RTX%202060%20SUPER~0,RTX%202060~0,GTX%201660%20Ti~0,GTX%201660%20SUPER~0,GTX%201660~0,GTX%201650%20Ti~0,GTX%201650%20SUPER~0,GTX%201650~0"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"
}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

# uncomment to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for p in data["searchedProducts"]["productDetails"]:
    availability = data['searchedProducts']['productDetails'].get('prdStatus')
    if availability == "out_of_stock":
        print("{:<10} {}".format(p["productSKU"], p["productTitle"], p["productPrice"]))
```

But i have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/thomas/Documents/Créatux/Clients/Scrap Nvidia/scrap-nvidia.py", line 17, in <module>
    availability = data['searchedProducts']['productDetails'].get('prdStatus')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I have change ['productDetails'] for ['featuredProduct'] its work but i can get SKU...

Thank.

Comment: should that be `p.get('prdStatus')`?

Comment: @gvee Yep i have result but i have add one more:
for p in data["searchedProducts"]["productDetails"]:
    print("{:<10} {}".format(p.get("productSKU"), p.get("prdStatus"), p.get('productTitle')))
I have only two results...

Comment: The error message is clear. It seems that *data['searchedProducts']['productDetails']* returns a list whereas you expected a dictionary

Comment: use `print()`, `print(type())` to check what you have on every level of you JSON. If some level has list then you need `[0]` to get first element from list - or use `for`-loop to work with every element on list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error shows you that `['productDetails']` is NOT `dictionary` but `list` and you may need to use `[0]` to get first element from list (and later use `.get()`)

```
for p in data["searchedProducts"]["productDetails"]:

    details = data['searchedProducts']['productDetails'] #.get('prdStatus')

    item = details[0]
    availability = item.get('prdStatus')
    if availability == "out_of_stock":
        print("{:<10} | {:30} | {}".format(p["productSKU"], p["productTitle"], p["productPrice"]))
```

or you should use `for`-loop to run `.get()` on every element from list

```
for p in data["searchedProducts"]["productDetails"]:

    details = data['searchedProducts']['productDetails'] #.get('prdStatus')

    for item in details:
        availability = item.get('prdStatus')
        if availability == "out_of_stock":
            print("{:<10} | {:30} | {}".format(p["productSKU"], p["productTitle"], p["productPrice"]))
```

---

```
NVGFT090   | NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3090        | €1,649.00
NVGFT070   | NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3070        | €549.00
NVGFT060T  | NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3060 Ti     | €439.00
NVGFT070T  | NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3070 Ti     | €649.00
NVGFT080T  | NVIDIA GEFORCE RTX 3080 Ti     | €1,269.00
```

---

Now you have to decide which version you need because they may give different result.

First check `prdStatus` only in first item and it may not have `out_of_stock` but other items may have `out_of_stock`.

Second check `prdStatus` in all items and it may repeate the same value if every item has `out_of_stock`

It may need first check all items and set some variable `True/False` when it find `out_of_stock` - and later display text

```
for p in data["searchedProducts"]["productDetails"]:
    details = data['searchedProducts']['productDetails'] #.get('prdStatus')

    # - first check all items -
    
    out_of_stock = False
    
    for item in details:
        availability = item.get('prdStatus')
        if availability == "out_of_stock":
            out_of_stock = True

    # - later display product only once -
    
    if out_of_stock:
        print("{:<10} | {:30} | {}".format(p["productSKU"], p["productTitle"], p["productPrice"]))
```